# Returning a string containing HTML in Python

Tags: python, html

I am just wondering if anyone could help me to get this function to work. I am wishing to return a string which contains an HTML list for each of the items given in a list.

```
def returnString(l):

hi = []

hi.append(l)

ol = "<ol>"

for i in hi:
    ol += "<li>"+i+"</li>"
ol += "</ol>"
return ol
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly and specify what the *exact* problem is and what the expected output is ? My gut feeling is that `hi.append(l)` fails because `l` is a list so try using `hi.extend(l)` or iterate over `l` directly

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of items in the list but assuming that they can be converted to string a possibility would be to do the following:

```
for i in hi:
    ol += "<li>"+str(i)+"</li>"
ol += "</ol>"
return ol
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution out.

It should return the list as expected:

```
def get_html_list(l):
    return '<ol>' + ''.join('<li>{}</li>'.format(e) for e in l) + '</ol>'
```

Answer (score 0):

why do do that so? ... normaly thats not the way to do such things. You should differ between model / controller and view.

you should only save the values in the list.

and in the views (html) you should iterate over the list. Probably you should use a framework to achieve this.

but saving whole html in the list isn't a nice way.